# Are literals type-cast at compile time?

Tags: c++, c

Does these lines produce the same compiled code?

```
double one = 1.0;
double one = 1.f;
double one = 1;
```

Or this three?

```
float one = 1.0;
float one = 1.f;
float one = 1;
```

---

**Edit**

Assume, that the values at the right side can be stored as a 32bit float

Comment: Yes to both. These type conversions happen at compile time.

Comment: In case of value "1" they very likely will, but in general case this may be platform/compiler dependent. With some double value (using the full double precision) the line ending with "f" should differ (not using full double precision, truncating/rounding it to float precision).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers. I've updated the question

Comment: @T33C: There's no guarantee of that.

Comment: This is going to be compiler-dependent (the standard does not require it), so you could answer this question yourself by looking at the object code generated by your compiler of choice.

Comment: It's a poor choice using `1.0` as an example value, because it can be *exactly* represented by `float` and `double` types. But the value `0.1` cannot be exactly represented by either type. Similar to your example `float one = 0.1;` and `float one = 0.1f;` might not give the same result, because the first assignment is a `double` value which is converted to `float`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit   If you think about how the compiler will generate the object code I think you will come to realise that these are guaranteed to be the same. (At least in the land of the sane.)

Comment: @T33C: Which compiler? Under what conditions and using what settings? You're misusing the term "guaranteed" on a question about the C++ _language_.

Comment: Depending where they are and your target platform they don't generate any code. Also C and C++ are different languages. This adds another dimension to the question. So: pick **one** language and provide a [mcve]!

Comment: @T33C: No to the title! Implicit conversions are no casts!

Comment: Nothing in the post is a C literal.  Recommend dropping C tag.

Comment: "Type-casting" is something that happens to TV and movie actors. Casting is an explicit conversion, using either a C-style cast (`(type)expr`) or one of the C++-style casts (`reinterpret_cast<type>(expr)` et al). Neither occurs here. The value of the constant (whose type is determined by the constant itself, independent of its context) is *implicitly converted* to the type of the object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're not allowed to be converted at compile time unless the compiler can prove that converting at compile time is equivalent to converting at run time. When the compiler can prove that, and for a lot of types it's easy, most compilers will perform the conversion at compile time.

But one example you give is of a conversion from a literal of type `double` to type `float`. This gets tricky. For compilers that support floating point status flags (which C compilers are required to support when the `FENV_ACCESS` pragma is used, even though neither gcc nor clang implement that pragma),  such a conversion potentially has a side effect of raising an "inexact" exception if the conversion from `double` to `float` would lose precision. In your case, precision would not be lost, but with e.g. `float f = 1.1;`, it almost certainly would be. If `float f = 1.1;` and `float f = 1.1f;` have visibly different behaviour, a compiler cannot turn one into the other.

Answer (score 3):

In practice, I'd be surprised if they didn't. The statements are very simple and can be trivially resolved at compile-time.

But, strictly speaking, you cannot and should not rely on this. Semantically there are conversions at play here, so the results may not be what you expect. If your code relies on this, odds are you're doing something weird anyway.